# Music on iPhone/iPad grouped bizarrely despite being fine on iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, ipad, music

I have some 'albums' in my iTunes library that look fine to me:

[image]

However, when I sync them to my phone and iPad, they become grouped in really weird ways:

[image]

If I play the album, all the songs are actually on the device:

[image]

I just can't see them in the actual listing.

I thought it might be the "Grouping" field in iTunes, but it's empty for all the songs, and the behaviour persists (even after several of the files have been replaced).

[image]

How do I get my devices to show me all my songs, not these weirdly grouped swap ins?  I'm on Windows, if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

There is an additional field in the data: “Work”.  It doesn’t appear in the “Edit info” box, but you can make it appear as a column in playlists and the like.

The misbehaving tracks had had “Work” values set; I deleted them, synced it across, and then they were showing up as expected.

Note that editing this field doesn’t seem to qualify as an “edit” for the sync to pick up automatically, so I had to modify something else to make it re-copy those files.  (I added a space to the end of the song name, synced, then removed the space and synced again.